# Do the same thing to all dataframes in a list

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr

I have a list of data frames and I need to do the same thing to all of them. I'm not sure if it would be best to create a function, or a loop and then apply it to everything in the list. I have tried both and I cannot get anything to work. I have tried:

```
    prepare_df <- function(df) {
      # make changes to df
      names(df)[1] <- 'row'
      df <- df %>%
        pivot_longer((!row), names_to = "plateColumn", values_to = "Broth_t0")
      df <- df %>%
        mutate(wellID = paste0(row, plateColumn)) %>%
        select(-c(row, plateColumn))
      return(df)
```

and I have tried:

```
      change <- function(i){
        i <- i %>% 
          pivot_longer((!row), names_to = "plateColumn", values_to = "Treatment") %>% 
          mutate(get(wellID = paste0(row, plateColumn))) %>%
          select(-c(row, plateColumn))
      }
```

I'm wondering if it is easier to do what I need to do step by step instead of trying to incorporate everything into 1 function/loop but I need to be able to do all of that is below. mr1_44_312_t0 is the individual dataframe and I have been just copying and pasting, but I have too much data to continue with that method. I am fairly new to R, so any help would be appreciated!

```
    mr1_44_312_t0 <- mr1_44_312_t0[36:43, 2:14]
    colnames(mr1_44_312_t0) [2:13] <- (1:12)
    names(mr1_44_312_t0)[1] <- 'row'
    mr1_44_312_t0 <- mr1_44_312_t0 %>%
      pivot_longer((!row), names_to = "plateColumn", values_to = "Absorbance_t0")
    mr1_44_312_t0 <- mr1_44_312_t0 %>%
      mutate(wellID = paste0(row, plateColumn)) %>%
      select(-c(row, plateColumn))
```

Comment: I would just use base R lapply(), definitely not imperative loops. If you evaluate the function: lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), f), it will return a new list containing f(df1), f(df2), f(df3)

Answer (score 1):

We may use `map` to loop over the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
out <- map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
          # select the columns 2 to 14
          select(2:14) %>%
          # subset the rows from 36:43
          slice(36:43) %>% 
          # reshape to long format        
          pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "plateColumn", 
          values_to = "Absorbance_t0") %>%
          # create the wellID
          mutate(wellID = paste0(cur_data()[[1]], plateColumn)) %>%
           select(-1, -plateColumn))
```